# Recommended IDE for R under linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, ide, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDEs are available for R in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097367/what-ides-are-available-for-r-in-linux)

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097367/which-ide-for-r-in-linux) from over a year ago, but I wonder if there's anthing new under the sun. Spedifically, I do not get along with Emacs so well...

p.s.
I use eclipse for java and perl programming.