# Which modern IDE do you use with R

Tags: r, ide

I realize that there was a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097367/which-ide-for-r-in-linux), but this is over a year and a half old and the landscape has changed quite a bit.  I'm not sure the accepted answer would be the same if asked today, so I'd like to get people's feedback.

There seems to be a lot of buzz going on for http://www.rstudio.org.  Have people changed over from previous IDE's to this one recently?  What were the impacts of this change (good and bad).  Has anyone done an analysis of the landscape recently.  What are your thoughts on the prior list?

This question is probably best as a wiki that people can edit as new IDEs come out for R.

Comment: There's also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1439059/271616), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3394068/271616). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1173463/271616) is already community wiki...

Comment: Thanks @Joshua.  I was looking for a wiki version of the question.  I try not to create duplicates, but sometimes what I'm looking for does not come up.  It seems that this is a bit of a problem, and could be improved so I added this entry to meta:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81740/allow-easier-wikifying-of-long-standing-dynamic-questions

Comment: to be clear, RStudio is a great frontend GUI for R. It is in no way even close to an IDE.

Comment: @Joris Meys From the RStudio website "RStudio is a new open-source IDE for R that runs either on your desktop or on a server"

Comment: It's not because they call it that, that it actually performs like that (debugging, correct code highlighting, project building, support for package development wasn't there last time I checked). But they're rapidly increasing its capabilities, so it might become another good alternative for developing in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made the switch to [Rkward](http://rkward.sourceforge.net/), which I enjoy a lot more than what I was using earlier: [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with [NppToR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npptor/). I hadn't heard of RStudio -- I'll have to check it out.  Thanks!