# Unable to clone git repository in Eclipse using https and SSH links

Tags: eclipse, git, gitlab, eclipse-luna

While trying to clone a Git repository in Eclipse Luna, I'm getting the error shown below using the https link:

[image]

I added the said values in the Git configuration using this link - ["SSL host could not be verified" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663010/ssl-host-could-not-be-verified-error) but I'm still getting the same error.

I'm sure that the URL is correct. Not too sure if there's something wrong with proxy settings (I don't think so).

On the other hand, I  tried the ssh link by generating keys and putting them into the enterprise gitlab account and also on the pc (windows) but I'm still being unsuccessful doing that and getting the same error shown in the image below except for the last point.

I checked the error log, while using the https link it says 'not authorized' and 'Auth fail' when I try to use the ssh link.

I'm listed as the member of the repository and I'm using my email and password of the enterprise account to access it, but no luck.

Help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the ssh or http you are trying to clone? Do you have credentials?

Answer (score 1):

I have face same problem. To resolve this problem make sure your repository access level is public. It will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using a private GitHub Enterprise in an enterprise, SSH URLS are rarely allowed.

For HTTPS URLs, you need to make sure your [proxy configuration ignore host setting in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3396485/6309) includes the domain name of the GitHub Enterprise (on premise) private server, or it will try to contact the proxy every time (and fail)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your company uses their own certificate authority, their root certificate has most probably been added to your computer's trust store. However, Java by default uses its own trust store, so Eclipse does not know about it.

The best solution is to make Eclipse use the system trust store. See [this answer for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65794452/4850949) or [this answer for macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57120998/4850949).