# Eclipse and R on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, r

Is it possible to get some type of add-in or something to be able to edit/run R programs in Eclipse on a Mac? I'm running Lion on my mac.

Comment: The Stat/ET package does what you're looking for.

Comment: @reising1 Are you incapable of using Google? http://www.walware.de/goto/statet

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Gavin provided you the information that you asked of gsk3, so I'd edit your comment to say "unnecessarily helpful and perhaps a bit gruff, bordering on the edge of rude"

Comment: I never thought I would live to see the day @Gavin would run out of patience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The StatET package for Eclipse works great on a Mac. Go to [StatET](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet) and follow his installation instructions. Sometimes it can be a little tricky to set up once the package is installed in Eclipse. There are several cheat sheets in Eclipse to assist with the setup. Look for them under Help->Cheat Sheets in Eclipse.

If you are using Eclipse 3.7 Indigo, you can drag and drop the plugin from the [Eclipse marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/statet-r).

Edit: There are many possible R development environments that will work on a Mac. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097367/what-ides-are-available-for-r-in-linux). Most of those run great on a Mac.