# Load an R function without having to manually select it

Tags: r, function, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any clever way to select a 'condensed function' by just clicking the line number and another key (R 3.0 on Mac OSX)? Currently when I select the line with the condensed function code only the first line of the code is selected and I have to manually select the last } to make sure it loads properly.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you use one of the IDEs that will greatly improve your workflow. There are many choices out there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097367/what-ides-are-available-for-r-in-linux) but recently, RStudio has been ahead of a lot of them.

Comment: Thanks. I will give R studio a go

Comment: Can't you just put the cursor on the line and hit *CMD* + *Enter*. I thought the editor in R on Mac was clever that way? (but my MBP is at home so I can't test that!).

Comment: @SimonO101 No I'm afraid it exclude the last } and in effect only runs the first line of the code. Seems like there would be some sort of cmd+ shortcut though....

Comment: If your text file contains just the function of interest,  <CMD>-e will `source` the entire file, hence load your function for you.  Recommend you read the R-OSX FAQ and what built-in help there is for `R.app` .